# What does the ~> operator do?

Tags: swift, operators

**What does the operator `~>` do in Swift?**

There isn't even a description on [swiftdoc.org](http://swiftdoc.org/operator/tildegt/) or Xcode 6.

Xcode shows error about collection: `…does not conform to _CollectionType`. If I use two collections I don't get a very helpful error then: `can not invoke with argument list of (@lvalue [Int], @lvalue [Int])`.

```
var coll = [1, 2, 3]
var coll2 = [4, 5, 6]

coll ~> coll2 // error wrong arguments
```

Comment: I found this: http://natecook.com/blog/2014/11/swifts-elusive-tilde-gt-operator (I haven't read it myself, but it's talking about the same operator)

Comment: Feel free to post it as the answer - I can't be bothered to do it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit:

See the duplicate: [What is the ~> (tilde greater than) operator used for in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26758297/what-is-the-tilde-greater-than-operator-used-for-in-swift)

---

I have only seen the ~> operator as a special threading operator. As described here: http://ijoshsmith.com/2014/07/05/custom-threading-operator-in-swift/

It takes two closures, executes the first one on the background thread, and the second on the main thread.

Please note that this is not standard Swift.

Comment: I think there is one defined in the standard library. I today tried it out, and the playground knows the `~>` operator without importing anything. (*seen it on swiftdoc.org first*)

Comment: I have not found one in de standard library.

Comment: That is the funny thing, it is not really documented, but it is in.