# What does ~> (tilde greater than) mean in this Swift code?

Tags: swift, operators, swift3, tilde

I am converting code that is not mine to swift 3.0 and there are some lines I don't understand that are being flagged by the compiler:

```
public func setupAppearance()
{
    if let delegate = delegate
    {
        firstWeekday~>delegate.firstWeekday?()
        dayOfWeekTextColor~>delegate.dayOfWeekTextColor?()
        dayOfWeekTextUppercase~>delegate.dayOfWeekTextUppercase?()
        dayOfWeekFont~>delegate.dayOfWeekFont?()
        weekdaySymbolType~>delegate.weekdaySymbolType?()
    }
}
```

NOTE this is not -> (dash, greater than) but ~> (tilde, greater than)

I did find this question:
[What is the ~> (tilde greater than) operator used for in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26758297/what-is-the-tilde-greater-than-operator-used-for-in-swift) but did not find it very helpful.

Can someone point me to docs on how to read this? Unfortunately google, stackoverflow and github can't search for ~>.

Thanks

Greg

Comment: Someone has created a custom operator (or better put: they've hijacked an existing operator to mean something else, which is worse). Command-click on it and see where it takes you. (One reason I discourage the use of custom operators…)

Comment: @RobNapier `~>` isn't "an existing operator", so what do you mean?

Comment: It actually is. It just doesn't have any public implementations. It's defined as an operator in the Swift header. It might be used as an implementation detail of switch cases if I remember correctly.

Comment: @TimVermeulen [http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/operator/tildegt/](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/operator/tildegt/).

Comment: I did find this: http://natecook.com/blog/2014/11/swifts-elusive-tilde-gt-operator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the original developer was using Swift custom operator for Thread Marshalling by [iJoshSmith](https://github.com/ijoshsmith/swift-threading).

```
func ~> <R> (
    backgroundClosure: () -> R,
    mainClosure:       (result: R) -> ())
{
    dispatch_async(queue) {
        let result = backgroundClosure()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            mainClosure(result: result)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, this code uses an undocumented Swift feature to copy the entire data structure from one object to another and this is done on the main thread?

Comment: What the Swift custom operator does is,  it executes the lefthand closure on a background thread and when that completes it executes the righthand closure on the main thread. You could also check your source code if it is indeed using this library or the original author of your code created his own implementation of that operator.

Comment: This is the correct answer in that they created their own operator:                                                                                                        infix operator ~> { }
public func ~><T: Any>(lhs: inout T?, rhs: T?) -> T? {
    if lhs != nil && rhs != nil {
        lhs = rhs
    }
    return lhs
}

Answer (score -4):

I believe these are bitwise NOT operators. See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html

> The bitwise NOT operator (~) inverts all bits in a number.

Comment: That's just `~`, not `~>`.