# Swift code compiler bug? Custom operator not working

Tags: swift, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

The custom operator ~*> works:

```
infix operator ~*> { associativity left precedence 90 }

public func ~*> <T> (left: Signal<T, NoError>, right: MutableProperty<T>) {
    right <~ left
}

element |> addAndClear(buttonClick, selectedSuperElementID) ~*> add
```

When I rename it to ~> it doesn't work:

```
infix operator ~> { associativity left precedence 90 }

public func ~> <T> (left: Signal<T, NoError>, right: MutableProperty<T>) {
     right <~ left
} 

element |> addAndClear(buttonClick, selectedSuperElementID) ~> add
```

This gives me an error of:

```
Binary operator '~>' cannot be applied to operands of type         
'MutableProperty<Element?> -> Signal<Element?, NoError>' and     
'MutableProperty<Element?>' (aka 'MutableProperty<Optional<Task>>')
```

Does anyone know why? I want to be able to use ~> because it fits much better with my naming convention.

I have been at this question for two days and can't seem to figure it out. It seems to be a compiler bug. I am using Swift 2.2.

**Someone in the comments solved it. Swift has a custom operator defined as ~> with precedence of 255. So I need to choose a different name. Hopefully in swift 3 it will be gone.**

Here are additional function definitions if useful:

```
infix operator |> { associativity left precedence 100}

func |> <Input, Output> (left: Input, right: (Input) -> Output) -> Output {
    return right(left)
}

private func addAndClear(buttonClick: MutableProperty<ButtonClick?>, _ superElementID: MutableProperty<Int?>) -> MutableProperty<Element?> -> Signal<Element?, NoError> {
    return { element in
        return combineLatest(element.signal, superElementID.signal)
            .sampleOn(buttonClick.signal.ignoreNil().filter { $0 == ButtonClick.add }.map { _ -> Void in })
            .map(self.addAndClear)
    }
}

private func addAndClear(element: Element?, superElementID: Int?) -> Element? {
    guard let _ = superElementID else {
        return nil
    }

    self.dateString.value = ""
    self.displayTask.value = ""
    self.nodeString.value = ""

    return element
}
```

This operator <~ is from reactivecocoa on github.

Comment: Where does the `<~` operator come from?

Comment: It is the binding operator from reactivecocoa. I have used it before with no problem in operator definitions. You can find reactivecocoa on github.

Comment: You should mention that in your question.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the feedback, Martin.

Comment: There is a [hidden `~>` operator in Swift's standard library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26758297/what-is-the-tilde-greater-than-operator-used-for-in-swift/38378548#38378548) with precedence 255, maybe that's the problem. Did you try if `(elem |> addAndClear(...)) ~> add` works?

Comment: Thanks that is the problem. You solved it kennytm. Hopefully in swift 3 they will remove it.